# Need to convert 21:45 to 21.75

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a datetime column with a time portion of `21:45`; I need to convert it to `21.75`. I tried:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATE,108)
```

This converts it to `21:45`, now the client wants this be `21.75`.

Comment: Ok, so in the table it's actually `datetime`, and that's going to stay that way? If this is a duration of something, it should be stored either as an integer (say, number of minutes) or as two datetime values (and you can always calculate duration as the delta between start and end). Datetime represents a point in time, not an interval, and this will bite you especially if you ever expand to durations >= 24 hours...

Comment: Yes, in the table it's actually datetime, the reason I convert it because I need to separate the date and time for the report. so 2015-09-01 21:45:00.000 becomes 09/01/2015 for date and 21:45 for time. So now I need to convert the 21:45 as 21.75. Even if we can covert it to 21:75 that would be fine because later I can use the REPLACE to replace the ':' with a '.'. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Your client wants to show time as fractional /100 instead of /60? And they don't care about sub-minute granularity? That's strange, as is the display of mm/dd/yyyy. Have them read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), please.

Comment: Hi Aaron, nice article by the way. Since the table that I'm extracting the data from is already built this way what would you suggest I should use to extract the date and time separately from the datetime column since I need to display them as two individual columns, secondly, convert the time to the format they are looking for? Thanks again. DZ

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(col DATETIME);

INSERT @x SELECT '20150901 21:45';

SELECT col, 
  d = CONVERT(CHAR(10), col, 101), -- AMBIGUOUS, REGIONAL, NOT RECOMMENDED!
  t = CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(DATE,col), col)/60.0) 
FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
col                        d             t
-----------------------    ----------    -----
2015-09-01 21:45:00.000    09/01/2015    21.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version,

```
select CAST(datediff(second, 0,  CONVERT(varchar(5),getdate(),108)) / (60.0 * 60.0) as  DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: Couple of problems due to simplicity: (1) bunch of extra decimal places that will need to be formatted away (2) the source data is not just a string, it's a datetime, and if you try your calculation against today's date, for example, you get an overflow error.

Comment: Updated with CAST and Convert